# Como alternar texto entre "mostrar / esconder" dentro de um button com javascript

Tags: javascript

Não sei nada de *Javascript*. Portanto mesmo sendo algo "simples" pra alguns pra mim é um bicho de sete cabeça. É o seguinte:

No código a seguir tem um script que  eu vou usar que esconde e mostra a div ao clicar no `button`, só que nesse script ai mesmo que eu clique mil vezes no `button` o valor dentro dele não muda!

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
    var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;

    if(display == "none")
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv">Conteudo</div>

<button type="button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">Mostrar / Esconder</button>
```

Eis então o que eu queria fazer! Gostaria que quando a `div` estivesse escondida o texto mostrado no `button` fosse *"mostrar"*, e quando a `div` estivesse a mostra eu gostaria que mostrasse *"esconder"*.

Ainda melhorando o script, gostaria que tivesse um efeito *fade*.

Se possível gostaria que isso fosse feito em javascript puro, porque não uso *Jquery* no meu projeto, então acho inconveniente colocar um arquivo de 100kb só por causa de algo relativamente "simples"

Comment: Você fez duas perguntas em uma... respondi a pergunta principal, mas acrescentar um efeito `fade` em JS puro está suficientemente dissociado a ponto de merecer uma pergunta separada. [Nesse link](http://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html) há uma técnica interessante, porém limitada (ele não coloca `display:none` no final). Buscando pelo assunto, há outras possibilidades, mas de todo modo é uma tarefa de razoável complexidade... (primeiro se anima `opacity` e só no final esconde - não dá pra animar "visibilidade")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tudo o que você precisa fazer é selecionar o botão (dê-lhe um `id` pra isso ficar mais fácil) e mudar o seu valor (`innerHTML`) durante o código do `onclick`:

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
    var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    var botao = document.getElementById("meuBotao");

    if(display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        botao.innerHTML = "Esconder";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
        botao.innerHTML = "Mostrar";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv">Conteudo</div>

<button id="meuBotao" type="button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">Esconder</button>
```

Comment: Boa tarde, eu gostaria de saber como mudar o valor do onClick ao clicar no botão.

Comment: @IWannaKnow Isso resolve? `botao.onclick = function(e) { ... };`

Comment: Eu fiz um teste agora com o setAttribute e deu certo. Obrigado pela indicação.

Answer (score 3):

Basta utilizar `innerHTML` para ler/definir o texto do seu `<button>`.

```js
$div = document.querySelector('.minha-div');
$button = document.querySelector('.handle-div');

$button.onclick = function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML == 'Esconder' ? 'Mostrar' : 'Esconder';
    /*
      ou...
      var inner = this.innerHTML;
      if(inner == 'Esconder')
          inner = 'Mostrar';
      else
          inner = 'Esconder';
      this.innerHTML = inner;
    */
    mudarEstado();
}


function mudarEstado() {
    var display = $div.style.display;
    if(display == "none")
        $div.style.display = 'block';
    else
        $div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="minha-div">Conteudo</div>
<button class='handle-div' type="button">Esconder</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma usando operador tenário e passando a referência do botão por parâmetro com **this** para poder alterar o texto do mesmo.

```js
function Mudarestado(el, btn) {
    
    var ele = document.getElementById(el);
    var display = ele.style.display;
    
    ele.style.display = display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    btn.innerHTML = display == 'none' ? 'Esconder' : 'Mostrar';

}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv">Conteudo</div>

<button type="button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv', this)">Esconder</button>
```