# botão Mostrar/Esconder

Tags: javascript

como eu faço para criar um botão de mostrar e esconder em javaScript sendo que ele deixe o conteudo escondido ja quando abro a página.e eu só clico primeiro pra mostrar e depois para esconder.

Comment: Poste o código do que já fez.

Comment: Possível duplicada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45832/como-alternar-texto-entre-mostrar-esconder-dentro-de-um-button-com-javascrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que é isso o que você quer:

O hide() oculta a div quando a pagina termina de ser carregada.
O toggle() é acionado pelo botão exibindo e ocultando a div

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#divConteudo").hide();

        $("#btnMostrarEsconder").click(function (e) {
            $("#divConteudo").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="divConteudo">
        Conteudo
    </div>
    <button id="btnMostrarEsconder" type="button">Mostrar e Esconder</button>
</body>
</html>
```