# Mostrar e ocultar botão com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho os seguintes botões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo do botão **INCLUIR**, tem um botão **GRAVAR**, que está setado como **HIDE():**, quando eu clicar no botão ***INCLUIR***, eu quero que o botão incluir fique setado como **HIDE();**, e o botão **GRAVAR** como **SHOW();**.

```js
$(function () {
  setDisabled(true);

  $("#IniciarTarefa").on("click", function (e) {
      $("#IniciarTarefa").hide();
      $("#submeter").show();
      e.preventDefault();
      setDisabled(false);

  });

  $("#FinalizarTarefa").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setDisabled(true);
  });

  function setDisabled(state) {
      $('.desabilita input,select,textarea, checkbox').each(function () {
          $("#submeter").hide();
          $(this).prop("disabled", state);
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn botoes" type="submit" id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa">
  <img src="~/Content/iconBtn/novo_16x16.png" />
  Incluir
</button>
<button class="btn botoes" type="submit" for="frmCliente" id="submeter"  name="IniciarTarefa">
  <img src="~/Content/iconBtn/gravar_16x16.png" />
  Gravar
</button>
```

Dessa forma, o botão **GRAVAR**, está vindo setado como **HIDE();** e quando eu clico em **INCLUIR**, o mesmo some, mas o botão gravar não aparece. Alguém sabe qual o motivo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [botão Mostrar/Esconder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98129/bot%c3%a3o-mostrar-esconder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É porque após *tentar mostrar* o botão `#submeter` dentro do evento de click no botão `#IniciarTarefa`, você está chamando a função `setDisabled()` que oculta novamente o botão.

Então basta condicionar a linha `$("#submeter").hide();` num `if` para esconder o botão apenas quando o parâmetro `state` da função `setDisabled()` for `true`:

```
if(state) $("#submeter").hide();
```

Exemplo:

```js
$(function () {
     setDisabled(true);

     $("#IniciarTarefa").on("click", function (e) {
         $("#IniciarTarefa").hide();
         $("#submeter").show();
         e.preventDefault();
         setDisabled(false);
         
     });

     $("#FinalizarTarefa").on("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         setDisabled(true);
     });

     function setDisabled(state) {
         $('.desabilita input,select,textarea, checkbox').each(function () {
             if(state) $("#submeter").hide();
             $(this).prop("disabled", state);
         });
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desabilita">
   <input>
</div>
<button id="IniciarTarefa">Incluir</button>
<button id="submeter">Gravar</button>
```

Comment: realmente, era isso!!!!! obrigado pela força! !!!

Answer (score 4):

Bata adicionar atributo de "hidden" ao botões:

```js
    $(function () {
        setDisabled(true);

        $("#IniciarTarefa").on("click", function (e) {
            $("#IniciarTarefa").attr("hidden", "true");
            $("#submeter").removeAttr("hidden");
            e.preventDefault();
            setDisabled(false);
            
        });

        $("#FinalizarTarefa").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setDisabled(true);
        });

        function setDisabled(state) {
            $('.desabilita input,select,textarea, checkbox').each(function () {
                $("#submeter").hide();
                $(this).prop("disabled", state);
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn botoes" type="submit" id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa">
                                <img src="~/Content/iconBtn/novo_16x16.png" />
                                Incluir
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn botoes" type="submit" for="frmCliente" id="submeter"  name="IniciarTarefa" hidden>
                                <img src="~/Content/iconBtn/gravar_16x16.png" />
                                Gravar
                            </button>
```