# Ocultar texto ao pressionar botão

Tags: javascript

Utilizei o código vindo de [outra pergunta do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45832/como-alternar-texto-entre-mostrar-esconder-dentro-de-um-button-com-javascrip) para que conseguisse esconder/mostrar um texto ao clicar em um botão, mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de já ter o texto ocultado ao iniciar o programa e, quando pressionar o botão, o texto ser exibido.

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  var botao = document.getElementById("btn");

  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    botao.innerHTML = "Esconder";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    botao.innerHTML = "Mostrar";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv">
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
</div>
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')"><h1>Esconder</h1></button>
```

Comment: troque as duas primeiras linhas por: document.getElementById('minhaDiv').style.display = 'none';

Comment: Também por  *CSS*  `.minhaDiv{display: none}`. Veja [Qual a diferença entre display:none e visibility:hidden?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44678/137387)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, aparentemente você não entendeu a base do DOM, então pra esclarecer...

Basicamente, o javascript dentro de uma página HTML, tem a liberdade de modificar elementos CSS, dentro de objetos HTML, como por exemplo a borda de uma  ou um tamanho máximo de um

.

Quando você chama um elemento HTML dentro de um script (usando `querySelector()` por exemplo), você "puxa" as informações do HTML em formato de objeto, que têm suas devidas propriedades.

Até aí, você tem suas noções básicas de interação script-web, ok?

Ao carregar, uma página vai ser exibida com as definições CSS que você estabelecer, então para começar invisível, deve estabelecer no objeto  que o `display: none`.

Seguindo isso, sugiro que dê uma estudada em [Objetos JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/JavaScript/Objetos/B%C3%A1sico), e nas noções básicas da linguagem, em algum site como a [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

À frente, o importante de se pensar é:

> Com `document.getElementById()`, você está acessando ao **DOCUMENTO**
> da página (`document`), e logo em seguida pedindo que procure e te
> retorne o elemento com **determinado ID**, através do **método**
> `getElementById()`

Como funciona a mudança dos elementos através do javascript então?

> **Você pode visualizar esse processo como uma **ÁRVORE**.**
>
> > Seu tronco é o `document`, e o primeiro galho é o de
> > `getElementById()`, que acessa agora seu elemento com id citado.
>
> Agora você quer acessar a característica *DISPLAY* desse elemento, que
> nesse exemplo será **none** ou **block**. A característica é acessível
> dentro do requisito `style`, do CSS.
>
> > > Então seguimos no galho `style`, e então na característica desejada, o
> > > `display`.
> > >
> > > > **O código então seria:** `document.getElementById('el').style.display;`

Com uma condicional simples você pode dizer que esse elemento recebe a característica ***none*** (não aparece) ou ***block*** (aparece), chamando uma função através do seu botão:

> `<button onclick='switch'></button>`

e no seu script, uma função como

```
function(){
let div = document.getElementById('minhaDiv');
div.style.display==='none' ? div.style.display = 'block' : div.style.display = 'none'
}
```

Enfim, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Para ter o texto ocultado ao iniciar o programa use  `style="display: none;"` no elemento

```
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display: none;">
```

O mais apropriado é alterar o texto do `h1` ao invés do botão

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("btn");
```

```js
  function Mudarestado(el) {
    var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    var h1 = document.getElementById("btn");

      if (display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        h1.innerHTML = "Esconder";
      } else {
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
        h1.innerHTML = "Mostrar";
      }
 }
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display: none;">
 <h1>Conteudo</h1>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')"><h1 id="btn">Mostrar</h1></button>
```